# Why do the characters % * + , - / ; < = > ^ need to be escaped in HTML attributes?

Tags: html

I have seen everyone doing attribute escaping for single `'` and double `"` quotes and I understood the reason why, but I don't understand why someone is doing attribute escaping with `% * + , - / ; < = > ^`.

Could you please let me know why we have escape these all things? Can you please give some example for this?

Comment: "*I have seen everyone doing the attribute escaping for...*" - I'm not saying this should not be done, but I don't think I've ever done it. Where? When? Which 'attribute'? Examples..?

Comment: Your question is too vague.

Comment: Here we go, https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_Attribute_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Common_Attributes

Comment: You linked to a source that seems to answer your question ("why"). The whole page is about XSS attacks and *"The reason this rule is so broad is that developers frequently leave attributes unquoted. Properly quoted attributes can only be escaped with the corresponding quote. Unquoted attributes can be broken out of with many characters, including `[space] % * + , - / ; < = > ^ and |`."*  What else are you asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because attributes don't need to be quoted.
This is valid HTML

`<img data-x=examplevalue />`

So it could be manipulated to prematurely terminate if the value were to contain the characters you mention.

`<img data-x=example>value />`

when escaped would become

`<img data-x=example&gt;value />`

Comment: `&amp;`? Rather `&gt;`.